# How to to resolve issue Fortify path manipulation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, path-manipulation

The following code always shows path manipulation problem. How to resolve it ?

```
string pathMaterData = ServerName + "\\MaterData\\";
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(ServerName, "\\MaterData\\")))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(ServerName, "\\MaterData\\"));
}
```

This line code problem only

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(ServerName, "\\MaterData\\"));
```

Comment: if you could give an example of what ServerName is when this fails, that would help.

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without seeing what results you are getting, but it looks like maybe you are over qualifying the path with slashes.

Try this

```
string pathMaterData = Path.Combine(ServerName, "MaterData")

if (!Directory.Exists(pathMaterData))
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(pathMaterData);
}
```